# How to move two objects with different distances in 3d camera but make it look orthographic

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I cannot think of the type of math to look up for this, but here is a graphic showing what I have and what I want:

[Two objects in perspective vs. orthographic space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz90v.gif)

Basically, I have two objects at different distances from the camera. I want them to overlap so when one moves, the other does to. I'm using a perspective camera, trying to get a simulated orthographic effect. The reason I'm trying to figure this out is I want to be able to click and drag something in 3D space and have it locked to the cursor despite the difference in distance. I tried many different things, but I'm just not that savvy with this level of math and my searches turned up nothing. Best I could think of is some proportional equation, but I couldn't figure that out either.

The white crosshair is moving by the mouse's delta position, and not projected using the Camera methods like WorldToScreenPoint().

As a side question, that's how I was originally trying to move the cursor; how can I achieve that too? Nothing I found in my search seemed to work.

Much thanks to anyone who can enlighten me!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use InverseTransformPoint, WorldToScreenPoint, and ScreenToWorldPoint for this. Explanation in comments

```
// assign using method of choice such as with inspector
[SerializeField] Transform whiteTransform;
[SerializeField] Transform redTransform;

// assigned in code below
Camera mainCam;
[SerializeField] float redCrossHairDepth;

// some setup
void Start()
{
    // cache main camera;
    mainCam = Camera.main;

    // get "forward" distance between camera and red crosshair
    redCrossHairDepth = mainCam.transform
            .InverseTransformPoint(redTransform.position).z;
}


// call me after white position is set
private void SetRedCrossHairBasedOnWhite()
{    
    // get screen position of white crosshair
    Vector3 whiteScreenPos = mainCam.WorldToScreenPoint(whiteTransform.position);

    // assign the red crosshair depth to z component
    whiteScreenPos.z = redCrossHairDepth;

    // convert back to world space
    redTransform.position = mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(whiteScreenPos);
}
```